# Redis RDB way smaller (203KB) than memory usage (716MB)

Tags: redis

I have a Redis instance that acts as a queue for Logstash and as database for Sensu, so ideally the queue is always almost empty, because Logstash is able to process the logs at the rate it's submitted to Redis and Sensu only stores the most recent measurements. However, when I execute check the memory usage on Redis, is says:

`root@b7588aa11859:/data# redis-cli info | grep memory
used_memory:751751344
used_memory_human:716.93M
used_memory_rss:774729728
used_memory_peak:754163560
used_memory_peak_human:719.23M
used_memory_lua:154624`

But when I check the size of the `dump.rdb` file, it says:

`root@b7588aa11859:/data# ls -lah
total 212K
drwxr-xr-x  2 redis redis 4.0K Apr 24 08:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 49 root  root  4.0K Apr 21 06:07 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 redis redis 203K Apr 24 08:22 dump.rdb`

Logstash seems to work fine; the logs are flowing into Kibana, the metrics into Grafana.

When I run `rdb -c memory dump.rdb` I get a lot of keys that use very little memory, only the `topbeat` key (I use topbeat for gathering metrics) uses significant memory:

`database,type,key,size_in_bytes,encoding,num_elements,len_largest_element
0,list,"topbeat",797811,linkedlist,1686,986`

However, 797811 bytes is still just 779 KB.

So why is Redis still taking up all that memory? Its memory usage has steadily been growing at the speed of ~300KB/minute for the last ~2200 minutes.

Here some logs:

`1:M 24 Apr 08:22:07.312 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
1:M 24 Apr 08:22:07.333 * Background saving started by pid 5648
5648:C 24 Apr 08:22:07.346 * DB saved on disk
5648:C 24 Apr 08:22:07.362 * RDB: 1 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1:M 24 Apr 08:22:07.449 * Background saving terminated with success
1:M 24 Apr 08:25:07.403 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
1:M 24 Apr 08:25:07.427 * Background saving started by pid 5657
5657:C 24 Apr 08:25:07.462 * DB saved on disk
5657:C 24 Apr 08:25:07.473 * RDB: 1 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1:M 24 Apr 08:25:07.527 * Background saving terminated with success
1:M 24 Apr 08:29:07.375 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
1:M 24 Apr 08:29:07.391 * Background saving started by pid 5660
5660:C 24 Apr 08:29:07.419 * DB saved on disk
5660:C 24 Apr 08:29:07.433 * RDB: 1 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1:M 24 Apr 08:29:07.492 * Background saving terminated with success
1:M 24 Apr 08:33:07.372 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
1:M 24 Apr 08:33:07.396 * Background saving started by pid 5661
5661:C 24 Apr 08:33:07.423 * DB saved on disk
5661:C 24 Apr 08:33:07.435 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1:M 24 Apr 08:33:07.496 * Background saving terminated with success`

Answer (score 0):

The size of RDB file is a different representation of the same data when its loaded into memory.

When you need to work with memory, where the point of Redis is optimizing *data access time* as much as possible, it may happen that the data may be organized in a way that the priority is the access time.

In opposite of memory optimization, when Redis performs snapshots into disk (RDB files), the priority isn't speed but limiting disk consumption, because as you know, Redis doesn't work with files and its data is persisted using a background process. That is, any write operation is first persisted *in memory* and there's no full guarantee that the whole data will hit the disk if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. However, do you have a suggestion what to do to prevent this growth in memory usage? If it continues this way for a couple of days, I won't have any free memory on my virtual machine anymore.

Comment: @Peter I suspect that it's something tied to the internal hashtable-like algorythm to reserve memory before it's going to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Redis, like many key-value store, does not free up memory when keys are deleted. So real memory usage of redis is basicly peak memory usage.

For more information check Memory allocation section of [redis documentation](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization).

Comment: I read about Redis not freeing up memory when keys are deleted, but I thought it re-used that memory for new keys? The input into Redis is stable, so the same amount of keys are deleted and inserted, so therefore I wouldn't expect a continuous growth in memory usage.